# crash report third party tools need API_KEY

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to add crash report on my windows phone app,

I am trying various third party crash report tools,

In Flurry its asking for a key called API_KEY

```
FlurryWP8SDK.Api.StartSession("FLURRY_API_KEY");
```

here what is this API_KEY , where can i find this key in my project.

In Bugsense also it need this.

```
BugSenseHandler.Instance.Init(this,"YOUR_API_KEY");
```

Can anybody tell me whats this API_KEY, and where it is exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google? http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API/Code

*APIKEY is the unique code for each application. This can be found by logging into the Flurry website, then by going to the link "Manage Applications" and finally by selecting the application desired.*